# HTML Agility Pack how can you find certain parts of text

Tags: c#, html, parsing

I am trying to get few variables from a website and there are about 30 occurrences of them. The issue I am having is I don't know how to search and rip certain parts of html due to the fact this html has all the stuff in one line and I need to get

name ( and the value ) 
hight ( value ) 
width ( value ) 
url (value )

and I need to link the height and width and then find the name and find the link

then need to save the link image to pc I have got the div class working

tried multiple nodesets and using regex ( regexs is bad very bad for html )

```
            var url = "https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/steyr-aug-a3-4cea993b9f0d47c6b1beed7877b17447";

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result)
                {
                    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                    {
                        string result = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Application.StartupPath + "rip.html", result);
                    }
                }
            }


            var path = Application.StartupPath + "rip.html";

            var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.Load(path);

            var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='dom-data-container']");
```

I am not sure how to look up say

name or what I need to look up the file I'm parsing is here
https://hastebin.com/igavulogax.js

and wanting to parse name and get value 
width and get value 
height and get value 
and url the url value then save the stuff out the url image with using the name value as the name for the image